# I'm having trouble pulling data from a table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, formatting

I'm trying to scrape two tables using beautifulsoup and running into a brick wall. Website: https://bgp.he.net/country/US I'm trying to grab the header row from the table, but for some reason can't get it to parse into a list so I can manipulate it. I then would like to grab data from each column and output it all to a JSON file.

Example:

```
for row in soup.find_all("tr"):

   #Append to list(?)
```

The delete unwanted entries?

I want to be able to output this to the JSON file and display it like this.

ASN #: Country: "US", "Name": XXX, "Routes V4", "XXXX", "Routes V6", "XXX"

Comment: are you getting `<Response [200]>`? Seems like for me Im getting `<Response [404]>`

Comment: No I am able to successfully print the HTML code. I can easily grab the code and use a print(soup.prettify()).

Comment: ah ok. can you add that code then to your quesyion above then?

Comment: nevermind. found my mistake. had a typo in the url. I'll have a solution in moment

Answer (score 1):

if you get response code other than `200` set User-Agent in headers, mine get `403 Forbidden`.

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'}
html = requests.get('https://bgp.........', headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
data = []
for row in soup.find_all("tr")[1:]: # start from second row
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    data.append({
        'ASN': cells[0].text,
        'Country': 'US',
        "Name": cells[1].text,
        "Routes V4": cells[3].text,
        "Routes V6": cells[5].text
    })

print(data)
```

results:

```
[
  {'ASN': 'AS6939', 'Country': 'US', 'Name': 'Hurricane Electric LLC', 'Routes V4': '127,337', 'Routes V6': '28,227'},
  {'ASN': 'AS174', 'Country': 'US', 'Name': 'Cogent Communications', 'Routes V4': '118,159', 'Routes V6': '8,814'}
]
```

get country and code

```
country = soup.select_one('h2 img').get('title')
# United State
country_code = 'https://bgp.he.net/country/US'.split('/')[-1]
# US
```

Comment: So hard cod the "ASN" and "country" entries instead of attempting to go header row: body text, header row: body text. THANK YOU. Going to give this a try.

Comment: because they are fixed string I will write it directly to make the code faster but of course you can improve it.

Comment: I wonder if instead of hardcoding US, I could apply a parser to the current HTML link and print the last two characters of the link. Therefore make this usable on numerous of there pages.

Comment: yup, certainly can do that in a loop and just have the suffix dynamic and iterate through the different values (ie. https://bgp.he.net/country/ES for Spain).

Comment: @JordanNewman I edited the answer to get the country

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach than the BeautifulSoup version below to give you options.

I like BeautifulSoup to parse, until I see `<table>` tags. Then I usually just go to Pandas to get the table as it can be done in 1 line, then I can just manipulate the dataframe as needed.

Then can just convert the dataframe to json (actually learned this from an ewwink solution a few weeks back :-)  )

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

url = 'https://bgp.he.net/country/US'

session = requests.Session()
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Language": "en"}


response = session.get(url, headers=headers)

tables = pd.read_html(response.text)
table = tables[0]
table['Country'] = url.split('/')[-1]




jsonObject = table.to_dict(orient='records')


# if you need as string to write to json file
jsonObject_string = json.dumps(jsonObject)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'ASN': 'AS6939', 'Name': 'Hurricane Electric LLC', 'Adjacencies v4': 7216, 'Routes v4': 127337, 'Adjacencies v6': 4460, 'Routes v6': 28227, 'Country': 'US'}, {'ASN': 'AS174', 'Name': 'Cogent Communications', 'Adjacencies v4': 5692, 'Routes v4': 118159, 'Adjacencies v6': 1914, 'Routes v6': 8814, 'Country': 'US'}...
```